# Given that $y = \frac{2x+1}{x}$, show that $x\frac{\mathrm{d}^{2}y}{\mathrm{d}x^{2}} + 2\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = 0$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Given that $y = \frac{2x+1}{x}$, show that

$$x\frac{\mathrm{d}^{2}y}{\mathrm{d}x^{2}} + 2\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = 0$$

My though process has been to differentiate and solve for y and substitute dy/dx with it in the equation. Maybe then rearrange for x and substitute as well? This and everything else I’ve thought of seems wrong though.

Advice on how to solve and hints would be greatly appreciated over providing the answer, please. Thank you

Comment: **Hint:** Find the first and second derivative, substitute and simplify and see if you get zero. I just tried it and it works. You can simplify $y = 2 + \dfrac{1}{x}$.

Comment: Use `\frac{}{}` instead of `\over`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proposed ODE is actually solvable:
\begin{align*}
xy'' + 2y' = 0 & \Longleftrightarrow x^{2}y'' + 2xy' = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (x^{2}y')' = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow x^{2}y' = a\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow y' = \frac{a}{x^{2}}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow y(x) = -\frac{a}{x} + b\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow y(x) = \frac{bx - a}{x}
\end{align*}

In the particular case of the proposed question, $a = -1$ and $b = 2$.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Looking at it now, the solution seems so obvious and simple. Thank you for taking the time to answer. This  was exactly the help that I needed!

Comment: @Raelyn You are welcome! I am glad I could help.